# Stuck at Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-doctor

When I enter `flutter doctor` command `Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ...` displayed in the screen but progress bar is not displayed. Actually command prompt screen look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just run `flutter upgrade` then see what is happening

Comment: still the same issue.